# What happens to Prometheus alerts if metrics stop coming?

Tags: alert, monitoring, prometheus

I have a Prometheus alert like this:

```
ALERT etcdNoLeader
    IF etcd_server_has_leader{job="etcd"} == 0
    FOR 1m
```

What happens if the `etcd_server_has_leader` metric stops generating data? 
Does the alert fire ? Does it do anything ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alert will stop firing. You'll generally want an alert on `up == 0` and depending on your setup possibly also `absent(up)`.

Comment: If the alert was not firing in the first place, it will not start to fire right ?